# Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.6.2. I've been trying to resolve this error in Flutter for past 4 hours but can't

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ysyas\AndroidStudioProjects\brucrew\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

  > Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.internal.version-check']
  >   Minimum supported Gradle version is 5.6.4. Current version is 5.6.2. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\ysyas\AndroidStudioProjects\brucrew\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

***Even after editing wrapper class I am getting this:***

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

  > No matching client found for package name 'com.example.brucrew'
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 18s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: try to open flutter project & android folder in android studio with internet connection on it will resolve all your issues

Answer (score 1):

Try to fix your problem using the workaround [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74714#issuecomment-770168224), especially this steps after editing your wrapper class:

> 2. Running a `flutter pub cache repair` once might help.
> 3. Do `flutter clean` between version changes (and other changes, as seen below, that are local to your project).
> 4. You might have to edit pub-cache files to get things to work, so make sure you're at the versions you want. Then you cannot repeat the
>    `cache repair` without making those changes again.